# Mixin doesn't apply to an element, but the box-shadow does

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I'm trying to add a box-shadow to an element via mixin, but it doesn't work. When I put the box-shadow into the element, it works just fine, but won't take to the mixin. Maybe I'm missing something small, but according to the guide on FreeCodeCamp, it should work just fine. Any help would be awesome

```
@mixin project-drop-shadows($offsetX, $offsetY, $color) {
  box-shadow: $offsetX, offsetY, $color;
  -webkit-box-shadow: $offsetX, $offsetY, $color;
  -moz-box-shadow: $offsetX, $offsetY, $color;
}

.project-tile{
 @include project-drop-shadows(5px, 10px, yellow);
  box-shadow: 5px 10px grey;
}
```

Comment: box-shadow: $offsetX, offsetY, $color; you should be giving offsetY as $offsetY. Its not getting the value

Comment: Adding the missing '$' doesn't change anything

Comment: you can chck it below

Answer (score 0):

```
@mixin box-shadow($x-axis: 0, $y-axis: 1px, $color: $default) {
  box-shadow: $x-axis $y-axis $color;
}

.box-shadow {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px; 
  background: #333;
  margin: 50px;
  @include box-shadow(5px, 5px, red)
}
```

[fiddle](https://codepen.io/riogrande/pen/grPoeb) you can check this. It is working fine.